# Setting headers for Odata client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've been trying to set authorization header value for `Odata` client. After I instantiate the client, I do it like this:

```
container.BuildingRequest += (sender, e) => OnBuildingRequest(sender, e, accessToken);
private static void OnBuildingRequest(object sender, BuildingRequestEventArgs e, string token)
{
    e.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
}
```

When debugging, it shows that the event handler gets triggered AFTER the request to the WEB API is made, which is really strange for me.
The documentation says:

> "This event is fired before a request message object is built"

What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

After lots of research, I found the cause of the problem: the event handler "BuildingRequest" doesn't gets triggered until you make an actual request, that is if you have a method something like:

```
public IQueryable<Package> GetPackages()
{
   return _container.Packages.AsQueryable();
}
```

"BuildingRequest" handler will not be triggered. You must execute it, that is do something like:

```
_container.Packages.ToList();
```

In order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it like this:

```
container.SendingRequest2 += new EventHandler<SendingRequest2EventArgs>(delegate (object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
{
    e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
});
```